# For the matrix A as given below, which of them satisfy $A^6=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

For the matrix A as given below, which of them satisfy $A^6=I$?

1. $A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
   \cos\frac{\pi}{4}&\sin\frac{\pi}{4}&0\\
   -\sin\frac{\pi}{4}&\cos\frac{\pi}{4}&0\\
   0&0&1
   \end{array}\right)$
2. $A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
   1&0&0\\
   0&cos\frac{\pi}{3}&\sin\frac{\pi}{3}\\
   0&-\sin\frac{\pi}{3}&\cos\frac{\pi}{3}
   \end{array}\right)$
3. $A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
   \cos\frac{\pi}{6}&0&\sin\frac{\pi}{6}\\
   0&1&0\\
   -\sin\frac{\pi}{6}&0&\cos\frac{\pi}{6}
   \end{array}\right)$
4. $A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
   \cos\frac{\pi}{2}&\sin\frac{\pi}{2}&0\\
   -\sin\frac{\pi}{2}&\cos\frac{\pi}{2}&0\\
   0&0&1
   \end{array}\right)$

I tried and conclude that the option 3 is correct by the technique of solving the equation$A^6=I$ and getting the sixth roots of unity. but i don't know whether it is correct or not. Kindly help me

Comment: Hint: these are all rotation matrices. Its powers are rotations by multiples of the angles.

Comment: To add to @juanrapha's answer, "1" represents the axis around which rotation is taking place. For eg: in (1) X and Y axes are being rotated by 45$^\circ$

Comment: ya i know for $2\times 2$ but its $3\times 3$ and more over how could i relate this the equation $A^6=I$?

Comment: @David : I suggest you to view answers to your previous questions and respond to those answers..Accept the one which you like or ask for more explanations if you think answer is incomplete...

Comment: The whole point is that these matrices have only four components that do a rotation. One of the three axis in all of them is the axis of rotation. So, now can you check the angle of rotation in each and check which would make $A^6=I$?

Comment: In case you don't know the formulas for 3D rotation matrices, see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us take the option (3). the matrix is a rotation matrix. The rotation is about the Y-axis. The X and Z axes are rotated by $\frac{\pi}{6}$. So $A^6$ is same as rotating X and Z axes by $\frac{\pi}{6}$ about the Y Axis, sizx times. This is same as rotating X and Z axes by $\pi$ about the Y Axis, the rotation matrix for which has -I.

Can you do the others now?